# Rstudio does not make plots with knit Word

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I seem to have discovered an odd behaviour with the knit Word command in RStudio

This works:

`````
 ```{r qplot, fig.width = 6, fig.height=6, message=FALSE}
 library(ggplot2)
 summary(cars)
 qplot(speed, dist, data = cars) + geom_smooth()
 ````
`````

this does not work

````
 ```{r q plot, fig.width = 6, fig.height=6, message=FALSE}
 library(ggplot2)
 summary(cars)
 qplot(speed, dist, data = cars) + geom_smooth()
 ```
````

returning this message:

```
 pandoc.exe: Could not find image `./test_files/figure-docx/q%20plot.png', skipping...
```

The issue seems to be with the name of the chunk (i.e. `qplot` vs. `q plot`). When there is a space in the chunk name the plot does not render.

It only seems to affect the rendering of Word documents. Rendering html works fine.

I'm using RStudio 0.98.1028 and R3.1.1 on windows 7.

Has anyone else encountered this behaviour?

**update**

a space after the chunk name also seems to elicit the same behaviour:

this does not work

````
 ```{r q_plot , fig.width = 6, fig.height=6, message=FALSE}
 library(ggplot2)
 summary(cars)
 qplot(speed, dist, data = cars) + geom_smooth()
 ```
````

Comment: In `knitr` `R Chunk codes` need to have unique `labels`.

Comment: Good point. This is dummy code to show the error. I get the same response in real code with unique names.

Comment: it's not at all surprising that it fails with a space in the chunk name -- I'm guessing that somewhere in the `knitr` documentation it warns against using spaces (and special characters such as / or : and possibly .?) in chunk names.  The problem with the space between the name and the comma is more surprising, but -- isn't the answer to this "well just don't do that" ... ?  Do you have a use case where this is a real problem?

Comment: I did a quick check to see if this was documented but couldn't find anything. My google-foo may have been weak though. No, it's not a 'real' problem, although it's odd (to me) that it's not an error when rendering HTML. I discovered the 'bug' while trying to finalize a report as a word document, I'd been proofing it in HTML and it worked fine. The fix required re-naming 50+ code chunks, which was kind of annoying (not to mention the hour it took to figure out why). At least I won't do this again.

Comment: If you think this is a bug (it could well be) you should contact the package author.

Comment: from http://yihui.name/knitr/options : `Avoid spaces and periods . in chunk labels and directory names`.  But the space-before-comma issue does seem (to me) reasonably interpretable as a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the solution in case someone runs across this in future.

From Ben Bolker in the comments `Avoid spaces and periods . in chunk labels and directory names` as stated in the knitr documentation http://yihui.name/knitr/options.

This error only seems to affect making plots using knitWord. Code chunks with `labels` that contain spaces and that don't have plotting commands render normally. knitHTML also seems to work fine regardless of if chunk `labels` have a space or not.

Answer (score 0):

````
# Let's make a plot
```{r ugly plot}
plot(btc_prices)
```
````

should apparently be

````
# Let's make a plot
```{r ugly_plot}
plot(btc_prices)
```
````

So no spaces... otherwise you'll waste hours googling and crying.